# struts2 losing cookies when calling other action

Tags: java, html, cookies, web, struts2

After creating several cookies in one action and placing them on the response, when I try to access those cookies in another action, the request is blank. Here's a portion of the code that created the cookies:

```
Cookie cookie;

cookie = new Cookie("cookieUserId", cookieUserId);
cookie.setPath(getText("cp.cookieDirectory"));

if(getText("cp.cookieDomain") != null
        && getText("cp.cookieDomain").length() > 0)
{
    cookie.setDomain(getText("cp.cookieDomain"));
}
response.addCookie(cookie);

cookie = new Cookie("iwif_web_sso_timer",
        getText("cp.cookieSessionIdleTimeout"));
cookie.setPath(getText("cp.cookieDirectory"));

if(getText("cp.cookieDomain") != null
        && getText("cp.cookieDomain").length() > 0)
{
    cookie.setDomain(getText("cp.cookieDomain"));
}
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Here is the code (in another action) that should retrieve the cookies. The action is implementing ServletResponseAware and ServletRequestAware:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

When I inspect what is returned to cookies, the cookies array is blank. Why? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the client accepting cookies? Do you see the cookies set in the response? Do you see the cookie values coming back in the subsequent request(s)?

Comment: Do you access those cookies in another action or another browser?

Comment: @StevenBenitez The client is accepting cookies and i can see the cookies set in response but the cookie values from the subsequent request is null.

Comment: @RomanC i'm trying to access those cookies in different action but same browser.

Comment: @bhuwan I mean do you see the cookie being set in the actual HTTP response and coming back in the HTTP request. You can use the Chrome developer console or Firebug for Firefox to see this type of stuff.

Comment: @StevenBenitez I used google live header to confirm the cookies being set on the response. its just that the cookies are dropped when the action is executed. and yes the cookies have max age of -1 that should make it last till the end of the session or shutdown of the browser.